# JSON data does not represent a valid service account credential - .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to authenticate google Apis to call google Real Time Update endpoints for google reservations.

This my code, the patchAsync method is customed but it never gets there

```
[STAThread]
        public static async Task UpdateBookingNotificationAsync(string bookingId, object payload)
        {
            

            try
            {
                string[] scopes = { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/mapsbooking" };

                GoogleCredential credential;
                using (var stream = new FileStream(JSON_KEY_FULL_PATH, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(scopes);
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("prova.txt", "dio");
                }
                Oauth2Service baseClient = new Oauth2Service(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential
                });
                ConfigurableHttpClient httpClient = baseClient.HttpClient;

                Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                   { "name", String.Format("partners/{0}/bookings/{1}", PARTNER_ID, bookingId) },
                   { "payload", payload.ToString() }
                };

                FormUrlEncodedContent body = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
                HttpResponseMessage responseString = await httpClient.PatchAsync(
                    String.Format("{0}/v1alpha/notification/partners/{1}/bookings/{2}?updateMask={3}",
                        ENDPOINT,
                        PARTNER_ID,
                        bookingId,
                        payload), body, CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

and this is my service account with sensible data censored

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "rest-c-012345",
  "private_key_id": "****",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- **** \n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "****@rest-c-012345.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "00000000000000000000",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/****@rest-c-012345.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

I keep getting title error:

```
JSON data does not represent a valid service account credential
```

The key data is fresh new and copy-pasted into the project and the docs don't say how google wants this data

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today but managed to resolve it by doing the following:

1. Pasted the service account JSON into Notepadd++ and ran 'Format Json'. You need the JSON add-on installed for that. Then copied the output and pasted.
2. And this is always a gotcha: Don't forget to rebuild the project where the `.json` file lives.

And that was it.